# How to count alphanumeric elements in excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, countif

My series is like below in excel.

```
804
335123
335123
1210FC245
1210FC245
182663
1220FC140
700107
139562
MANUAL
```

The result should be '3' as it contains alphanumeric values but not only number or only characters.

Answer (score 0):

I used 3 intermediary steps to arrive at the answer. I don't if this is the best way to solve this problem, but it certainly is one way.

Formula View:

[image: Formulas View]

---

Output:

[image: Values View]

**Update**

Here I've shortened the process by combine two of the previously used intermediary steps.

Formula View (V2):

[image: Formula View]

The output remains the same, as expected.

Comment: Hi Onel, Thanks for the approach, I had huge data in several columns. Not sure how I can apply to my case.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a User Defined Function (aka UDF).

```
Function countAphaNumeric(rng As Range) As Long
    Dim a As Long, n As Long, str As String, r As Range

    Set rng = Intersect(rng, rng.Parent.UsedRange)

    For Each r In rng
        str = r.Value2
        For a = 65 To 90
            If CBool(InStr(1, str, Chr(a), vbTextCompare)) Then Exit For
        Next a
        For n = 48 To 57
            If CBool(InStr(1, str, Chr(n), vbTextCompare)) Then Exit For
        Next n
        countAphaNumeric = countAphaNumeric - CBool(CBool(a <= 90) And CBool(n <= 57))
    Next r

End Function
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

With helper column in B2 write:

```
=--(SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIF(A2,"*"&ROW($A$1:$A$10)-1&"*"))>0)
```

Then just SUM your result

```
=SUM(B2:B1000)
```